# NullPointerException when trying define the target url in the ProviderSignInController

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-social

I recently finish the implementation of the spring-social in my current spring project, but I have one unique problem that still bother me: in my SocialContext class (which implements SocialConfigurer), I try define the target url for where the application goes after the signin, in this way:

```
@Bean
public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, UsersConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
    ProviderSignInController controller = new ProviderSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository, signInAdapter);
    controller.setApplicationUrl("/");
    return controller;
}
```

but when I deploy the application, this fails because of a NullPOinterException caused by the line `controller.setApplicationUrl("/");` (if I comment this line, the applications is deployed correctly and runs without problem, except after the login it returns to the signin page).

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439777/how-to-set-redirect-url-after-success-login-using-social-providers) seems to cover a similar problem. Basically, if you are  using annotations to configure Spring and security, you might try something like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityContext extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/signin")
            ...
            // the rest of the configuration
            ...
            .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .and()
            .apply(getSpringSocialConfigurer());
    }

    private SpringSocialConfigurer getSpringSocialConfigurer() {
        SpringSocialConfigurer config = new SpringSocialConfigurer();
        config.alwaysUsePostLoginUrl(true);
        config.postLoginUrl("/");

        return config;
    }
}
```

Comment: where I should place this method?

Comment: Ok, this don't cause an error, but don't have any effect either (the application don't go to the desired place after the signin).

Comment: Maybe you are using a different configuration, is `configure()` getting called at all?